# How to disable copy paste events in React antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design Forms in my React applpication. I would like to know how do I prevent user from copying and pasting the values in that input field.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import { Input } from "antd";
```

```
<Input onPaste={(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault()
      return false;
    }} onCopy={(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault()
      return false;
    }} placeholder="Basic usage" />
```

Comment: why does it need to return false? It seems to work without it.

Comment: No, for me without 'e.preventDefault()' it did not work. I think we need to add it.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this on a plain HTML input in React:

```
 <input
        type="text"
        onPaste={(e: any) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }}
        onCopy={(e: any) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }}
      />
```